# QML iterate through delegate items in GridView

Tags: gridview, qml

I have a QML GridView which uses a ListModel. Each ListElement simply defines a color which the delegate reads and creates a colored square.

Is there a way to iterate through the delegate instances and call a function defined in the delegate?

Comment: QML views may create and destroy objects at any time (basically they hold only objects in viewport). Therefore, what are you trying to accomplish? Possibly, there is another way to do that.

Comment: As mentioned below in a comment to Deadron's post, I managed to achieve the functionality I desired by connecting a slot from each delegate instance to a signal from the parent container object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this question is a little light on details. If you can explain a little more what you are attempting to do it may be helpful.  Why is it that you want to iterate through the delegate and call functions on them?  Keep in mind that Views are used to render QML for each element in the List Model where the model merely supplies data, they are not designed to execute functions.  As it is you cannot even assign a function to a ListModel element since QML (last time I checked) does not support assigning functions to properties.

Comment: After revisiting my wording of this question, I have to agree that it was poorly laid out. I was unfamiliar with how signal/slot connections worked in QML and I was able to achieve the functionality by connecting a slot in each Delegate instance to a signal from its parent container.